# How to remove OS-specific commits from feature branch for pull request?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm working on a branch `Feature` based off branch `Ubuntu-Env` where some changes are made for me working with Ubuntu. These changes have to be deleted when I make a Pull Request. Until now I just checkout the changed files from master. Is there a more elegant way? I tried `git rebase` but the commits from Ubuntu-Env are still there.

Comment: What do you mean by deleting changes before making a pull request? What is then proposed to be merged? 

One way is to squash all commits in to one single commit before creating a pull request. This way only one commit will be added to the current master tree.

Comment: All commits I made to the branch feature but none of the commits from Ubuntu-Env should be merged.

Comment: Ah, you've created a new branch from your ubuntu env branch? One solution could be to step to master, create a new branch, then cherry-pick the commits you want to the fresh branch. And create a pull request from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commit history probably looks something like this:

```
*--*--*--* [master]
 \
  A--B [Ubuntu-Env]
      \
       *--*--*--* [Feature]
```

And you want to open a pull request to `master` from `Feature` that doesn't contain commits `A` or `B`.

You are on the right track with `git rebase`. However, you need to include the `--onto` argument:

```
git rebase --onto master Ubuntu-Env Feature
```

Your history will then look something like this:

```
*--*--*--* [master]
 \        \
  \        *--*--*--* [Feature]
   \
    A--B [Ubuntu-Env]
```